# Error ITMS-90046 when using xcodebuild instead of Xcode IDE

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, ios-provisioning, code-signing-entitlements

I'm unable to get rid of "ERROR ITMS-90046" when building my app with xcodebuild and uploading using Application Loader.  But it works fine if I archive and upload completely within Xcode.

The ITMS-90046 error message specifically complains about the "application-identifier" in my framework:

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application
>   bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not
>   supported on iOS. Specifically, value '*TEAMID*.com.domain.Product'
>   for key 'application-identifier' in
>   'Payload/Product.app/Frameworks/MyFW.framework/MyFW' is not supported.
>   This value should be a string starting with your *TEAMID*, followed by a
>   dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier.

I tried all the solutions mentioned in [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429043/error-itms-90046-using-xctool-xcodebuild-vs-xcode-archives-success), but none of them worked for me.  Luckily I am at least able to upload via Xcode, but this needs to happen frequently enough to become burdensome.

Any ideas what to try next?  Anyone know if Apple is even aware of this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the same building from the command line, With Xcode 8 however, it crashes when I try to upload from within Xcode. My Open Radar issue: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6177507581624320

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to re define and download all apple developer certificates and import them all again to Xcode.