# ERROR ITMS-90046: Invalid Code Signing Entitlements for embedded frameworks from cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing, signing

My customers want to resign the app when submitting to the AppStore. They will not give me their Certificates and Provisioning Profiles. And they will not add me to their development team in Apple Developer Account. They have tried a variety of signing methods and scripts. Including https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign and an upgraded version https://github.com/0xMarK/iReSign

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically value '12345678.com.mydomain.AppName' for key 'application-identifier' in 'PayLoad/AppName.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts' is not supported. This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier."

[image: ERROR ITMS-90046]

Isn't my 'application-identifier' is of correct format? I don't get it.

How do customers successfully resign our app?

I have found a thread on Apple Forum which describes my problem https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/94152

My `Podfile` includes `!use_frameworks`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877677/apple-store-submit-fails-with-error-itms-90046-but-associated-domains-is-not-am

Comment: @memedina thanks for response, but that does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in pods frameworks and managed to upload the application to AppStore after the following steps:
- Create a new *plist* file
- Rename it to *MyApp.entitlements*
- Add `application-identifier` key with `MYTEAMID.com.mycompany.myapp` value

Comment: I have tried to use this keys in `entitlements` file. This does not help:

    `<key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>9SK6DP2U5W.com.domain.MyApp</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>9SK6DP2U5W</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>beta-reports-active</key>
    <true/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>9SK6DP2U5W.*</string>
    </array>`

Comment: @MarK: I only have the first line in my `.entitlements` file. Not sure if this remark help.

Comment: @deko Could you kindly elaborate where did you add this file. Iam re-signing an IPA using a shell script and am getting the same error however not sure where to use the .entitlements file you mentioned since the 'application-identifier' key is already in my entitlements.plist file

Comment: @KaushalKapoor It was long time ago, but suppose, I placed this file inside each framework, where the error message points.