# ERROR ITMS-4238 Redundant Binary Upload after fixing a 90164/90046 error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Trying to upload to the App Store. First I got `ERROR ITMS-90164/90046: Invalid Code Signing Entitlements` which I solved from this [ERROR ITMS-90164/90046: Invalid Code Signing Entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106791/error-itms-90164-90046-invalid-code-signing-entitlements) by Cleaning and Archiving again. But now after I cleaned an Archived, when I try to upload the new Archive I get this:

`ERROR ITMS-4238 Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '1' for train '1.0' at Software Assets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset`

How do I get rid of this file that already exists? It didn't even go thru because of the 90164/90046 error. I have no idea where to find this `Software Assets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset` folder

edit: okay no idea how this works because despite that both times I tried to upload from Xcode I got errors, I now see the app build in the itunesconnect account. So I guess the first one went through anyways? Very confused.

Comment: Every upload you submit needs an increased build number.

Comment: yea but I haven't submitted yet, this is my very first submission and it gave me an error each time it tried to submit so I thought it didn't go through

Comment: The error says otherwise. Simply increase your build number and move on.

Comment: would you happen to know if I can submit my build for the first view without screenshots then add them later (before I manually release)? Or does the code and screenshots all need to be submitted at the same time for the first submission?

Comment: You can't submit for review until the screenshots are uploaded. Other than that you can upload the binary and tweak all of the meta data all you want.

Answer (score 13):

Increase your app's build number. If you were using Version 1.0 and build 1.0.1 for the earlier version, then make your current one Version 1.0 and build 1.0.2 Thank you.