# iOS - How can I remove entitlements from a Framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I'm getting dreaded errors like this:

> ERROR ITMS-90164: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements
>   in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained
>   in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile,
>   the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed:
>   'XXXXXXXX.com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx' for the key
>   'application-identifier' in
>   'Payload/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/Zip.framework/Zip'"

and this

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application
>   bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not
>   supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'development' for key
>   'aps-environment' in
>   'Payload/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/iOSDFULibrary.framework/iOSDFULibrary'
>   is not supported."

And it only happens when archiving and uploading to the appstore. Development on a physical device works just fine.

I already tried everything on this post without success [ERROR ITMS-90164/90046: Invalid Code Signing Entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106791/error-itms-90164-90046-invalid-code-signing-entitlements)

My specific scenario is that the errors are happening on manually installed Frameworks, while the Cocoapods frameworks seem to be fine.

I just also noticed this which made me come and create the question. Right before uploading the build to the App Store, on the final summary page, I noticed that Cocoapods frameworks look like this:

[image]

While the problematic frameworks (non cocoapods) look like this:

[image]

Those extra entitlements look like are to blame, but I can't figure out how to remove them.

EDIT Aug 3:

Just wanted to add that I found official documentation about entitlements troubleshooting [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2415/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016427) [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1879/_index.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2311/_index.html)

But it all talks about the app itself and not the frameworks.

Can anyone help me figure this out? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issue for my app. I have used xcode10.1 to generate xcarchive and upload ipa from xcode instead of using application loader. 
[ERROR ITMS-90164/90046: Invalid Code Signing Entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106791/error-itms-90164-90046-invalid-code-signing-entitlements) has multiple solutions.