# ERROR ITMS-90046: value 'Development' for key 'com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment' is not supported

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, provisioning-profile, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'Development' for key 'com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment' in 'Payload/AppName.iOS.app/AppName.iOS' is not supported."

"Development" isn't even in the entitlements.plist. There is the name of the iCloud certification though in an array of strings (this worked on the previous upload, I don't know what caused it to break). I've also tried deleting all certifications and provisions and redoing them. no change.

I've also tried the following to no avail:

[ERROR ITMS-90164/90046: Invalid Code Signing Entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106791/error-itms-90164-90046-invalid-code-signing-entitlements)

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48831/tinyurl.com/oqbw7ra

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58051/ios-entitlement-error-90046

Suggestions?

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.networking.wifi-info</key>
    <true/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.PrivateAppName</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>iCloud.com.PrivateAppName</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Are you using `icloud` in your project?

Comment: Xamarin.essentials.preferences and secure storage.

Comment: In my Entitlement I specify Environment like this:    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment</key>
  <string>Production</string> // In debug mode i comment it out and while releasing the app I un- comment it.

Comment: Can we see your Entitlement.plist?

Comment: updated. I tried using the "Production" string but it didn't work.

Comment: I looked into Xamarin.essentials.preferences and secure storage. they don't seem to use iCloud. will try removing it and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up removing the iCloud as I found a way to not use it. I used [secure-storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android) and [preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android) instead. Note that the keys used to store them must contain the app identifier, for whatever reason, otherwise it doesn't always pick it up from the device (phone, tablet, etc).