# Universal Links with Expo and Branch: Entitlements Error

Tags: ios, expo, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I am trying to set up expo universal links, so when a user presses my link and has my app downloaded on their phone, they will immediately be sent into my app. I am trying to achieve this with Branch.io. I am attempting to [follow the documentation.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/branch/) First, I added associated domains:

[image: Associated Domains Added Through Apple]

Then, I went to branch, put in my bundle and Apple App prefix. I then got my link domain:

[image: Getting my Link Domain From Branch]

Finally, I configured my App.json (I only show the relevant code here):

```
   {
  "expo": {

    "scheme": "librexapp",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],

    "ios":{

      "bundleIdentifier": "[Redacted]",
      "associatedDomains":
        ["applinks:librexapp.app.link"],
      "config":{
        "branch":{
          "apiKey":   "[redacted]"
      }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

And when I went to upload to the app store, I got the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/[Redacted]'."

I am not sure where I went wrong. I approached expo support and they said to clean my provision profiles and linked to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106791/error-itms-90164-90046-invalid-code-signing-entitlements). So I deleted all of them and remade, but the error persists. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please check that your bundle identifier is the same as your provisioning profile bundle identifier or the different one.

Comment: They look the same! I tried making another provisioning profile and clearing the old one, but I get the same error :(

Comment: Tried revoking old certificates and profile? And also delete the derived data

Comment: it due to old provisioning profile!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the problem  is explained in this paragraph:

"While some of the properties defined in app.json can be applied at runtime, others require modifying native build configuration files. **For ExpoKit projects, we only apply these settings once, at the time the native projects are generated (i.e. when you run expo eject).**
This means that for existing ExpoKit projects, changing certain properties in app.json will not have the desired effect. Instead, you must modify the corresponding native configuration files. In most cases, we've provided here a brief description of the files or settings that need to be changed, but you can also refer to the Apple and Android documentation for more information."

this is from [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/)

As a solution maybe you can try to regenerate the app for the ios.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you have added <> in your app links["applinks:"]

Please remove <> and it must be something like this ["applinks: librexapp.app.link"],