# iOS - Share a Today Extension with multiple app targets?

Tags: ios, widget, target, ios-app-extension, today-extension

I have a project with multiple app targets (about 25).

I'm going to make a Today Extension for those apps but I don't want to create about 25 extensions with the same code and configuration.

Is it possible to create only one Today Extension that I assign to the 25 apps ?

Comment: did you find the answer? i'm stuck with this and even tried UserDefinedConstants, but still have an error about wrong prefix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26310020/1387413 did u see this? but in this way you will have to create about 25 widgets, but with one source code for all widgets

Comment: @pash3r I don't want to have 1 extension for each targets, but 1 extension for all the targets.

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot Did you solve this any better than the answer below?.. It feels wrong to do it like that. I'd like an automated solution.

Comment: No, I had to make on extension by targets...

Answer (score 8):

It is possible, but with some manipulations. To connect extension with a target you need:

1. Add your extension to target's embedded binaries ("General" tab of project's settings)

[image]

2. Add extension's target to target dependencies ("Build Phases" tab of project's settings)

[image]

3. Prefix your extension's bundle identifier with the parent app's (your current target) bundle identifier or you will get an error:

[image]

So when you will build or distribute your target make this manipulations and fix provisioning profile's issues with Xcode (it can do this automatically).

Comment: I gonna try and come back if fails. Sorry for late answer but I was a bit busy ^^