# Add iMessage sticker pack extension to multiple targets (multiple bundle IDs)

Tags: xcode, ios-app-extension, imessage

I've tried a couple different methods and they have not worked.

I have three targets with bundle id's like:

> com.something.**myapp**
>
> com.something.**myapp-test**
>
> com.something.**myapp-staging**

I've made a sticker pack using File > New > Target.. and selected the app to embed it in (`com.something.myapp-test` in this case), but I would like it to be a part of all three without having to make multiple extension targets.

The problem is that the extension bundle ID is now something like:

> com.something.**myapp-test**.stickerPack

and will not build with a parent bundle id like:

> com.something.**myapp**

Does anyone know a good clean way to do this? I've come up with some hacks and what has worked best is manually changing the extension bundle ID each time, but that doesn't seem like good practice.

---

**Note:** This is for the new iMessage sticker packs that are JUST image assets. The extension doesn't have any files that I've written.

Comment: any update for this?

Comment: Ended up making three separate targets. Not going to put it as an answer though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS extensions with multiple targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398636/ios-extensions-with-multiple-targets)

Comment: I think that may solve it. Have not had a chance to verify